# I have a loop that creates a list and I need to run that loop a certain amount of times and get the average of the sum of all the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to run the loop a certain amount of times and get the average of the sum of all the lists.

```py
while len(randoms2) < 252:
    number = np.random.normal(0,1,None)
    randoms2.append(number)

while count < 252 * value:     
    number2 = np.random.normal(0,1,None)
    randoms3.append(number2)
    randoms = [sum(x) for x in zip(randoms2, randoms3)]
    new_randoms = [sum(x) for x in zip(randoms, randoms3)]
    count += 1
```

The results don't produce an error, but they are too small to be correct as I run the loop 1000 times

Comment: what is `randoms2`? please explain with example what you mean by `the results don't produce an error but they are too small to be correct as I run the loop 1000 times`

Comment: 'sum of all the lists'? Which lists and what is randoms2? I guess randoms2 = [] before the loop or something?

Comment: In each iteration of your loop, you overwrite your `randoms` and `new_randoms` without ever using them. You probably need to rethink your code logic.

Comment: So basically randoms2 and randoms 3 are empty lists to add the 252 numbers in and then add them together hopefully.

Comment: They are too small because when I run the loop once the numbers are between -1 and 1 and when I run it 1000 times the largest it goes to is 3 which I find a bit weird

Comment: and what is `value` ? This question is super unclear. Please state your current output and your expected output as well in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
random_sum = [0 for i in range(252)]

for _ in range(1000):
    randoms2 = []
    randoms3 = []

    for _ in range(252):
        randoms2.append(np.random.normal(0, 1, None))
        randoms3.append(np.random.normal(0, 1, None))

    temp = [sum(x) for x in zip(randoms2, randoms3)]
    random_sum = [sum(x) for x in zip(random_sum, temp)]
```

randoms2 and randoms3 are generated 1000 times and summed together.

In your code your sum didn't grow because you kept overwriting new_randoms (which I assume is supposed to be the sum?). So basically you had the sum of only one loop.

Also your randoms3 keeps on growing, so if value is 1000 it'll be 252000 long, and once it reaches 252 the sum is always the same (the length of zip(a, b) will be the length of the shorter list, so the new values added to randoms3 doesn't change anything). In my code I filled both lists before summing them.

I got a minimum of about -125 and a maximum of about 122 in random_sum when I ran this once.